# Error in Xamarin Studio: need latest version of Android Support Repository

Tags: android, sdk, xamarin.android, android-support-library, xamarin-studio

I installed the latest SDK platforms for Android 6 and 7. Upon installing and launching Xamarin studio, I got two error message saying to install the latest version of "Google Repository" and "Android Support Repository". I installed the latest version and the error message for "Google Repository" went away but other didn't.

I tried deleting "Android Support Repository" and re-installing, re-booting and none help.

Is their way to fix this error?

Error Message:

Partial Download Failed for one or more parts
A task was canceled.
Please open the Android SDK Manager and install the latest version of 'Android Support Repository' from the 'Extras' section, and then reload your solution.